# PostgreSQL - how to sync table between two database (not all fields)?

Tags: postgresql, synchronization

I have two PG database A and B.
From Table1 of A I need take 5 columns and sync them with Table1 of B every time when they are changing (or adding new) in DB A.

Not all columns, just specified.

Comment: You can use postgre_fdw with trigger

Comment: with triggers if you need data materialized, and if not just `create foreign table` (defining only 5 "foreign" columns) - the foreign table will be in sync as much as network is up (which anyway is needed for any type of sync)

Comment: Vao, if I right understand `create foreign table` will work only if two tables in same database.